# how to solve problem with label marker? google maps v3

Tags: javascript

I have n markers that I charge and from a query, there are some locations that are very close or are the same position, due to this when I show them on the map the following problem occurs that I show below, I wish that the markers can be visualized all regardless of whether they are very close or in the same position.

[image]

I had icons before and I didn't have that problem.

[image]

I have this currently:

```
fnShowRutas(datos:any){
    let data:any[]=[] = datos.filter(item => item.lat != "");

    this.options = {};
    this.overlays = [];
    let over: any[] = [];

    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    data.map((item, it) =>{
      it = it +1; 

      over.push(
        new google.maps.Marker(
          {
            position:{
              lat:Number(item['lat']),
              lng:Number(item['lon'])
            },
            title:item.nme,
            label:{
              text: ''+it,
              color: 'white',
            },
            visible: true

          }
        )
      )
         this.overlays = [...over]
          setTimeout(()=> { 
              this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
          }, 10);

          over.forEach(marker => {
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
          });
    })
  }
```

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: I don't really have time to go into it right not but the marker clustering that is shown on that page is useful if you have an application that needs to zoom further and further in to show different levels of data. If you have a situation where some markers need to be rendered as a cluster until you have gone past a certain zoom level it is easier to describe that in your data format, and render accordingly.